# What is a naming directory?

Tags: java, jndi

I am reading about JNDI and if I have understood the things I have read so far then JNDI is an API for getting resources from naming directories such as LDAP, DNS etc.

I have not heard of naming directories before and I tried to Google it for explanations. I read that it is a directory that stores names and objects (something like HashMap in Java?). However I do not understand what a naming directory is..., nor do I understand how JNDI works completly.

I would been more than happy if somebody could explain or/and give links to sites for further reading and helping me understand.

Thank you.

(PS, sorry for bad post tagging but I don't know where to put it)

Comment: JNDI stands for "Java Naming AND Directory Interface". There's no such thing as a "naming directory". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JNDI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some documents and tutorials from Oracle:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jndi/index.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/information/download.html

[JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2000/jw-01-howto.html) also has  an interesting article on the subject

Comment: The second link you provided is sooo old. I remember trying to run samples from that tutorial like 2 years ago, and nothing worked. I might consider to revisit it now. Maybe with my current level of understanding it will be much simpler to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Basically a directory service is a method for storing large amounts of (often heterogenous) structured data, organize it hierarchically (this includes complex authorization schemes) and allow clients to access each data item via a unique name.

It's basically like a filesystem, but optimized for very deep hierarchies of very small files that are accessed simultaneously by many clients over a network.

In the context of Java EE, JNDI is mainly just used as a level of indirection, to avoid hard-coding dependencies like EJBs and data sources. Instead, they're looked up via a name,  which allows them to be configured at runtime. This serves the same purpose as a dependency injection container, and in fact Java EE dependency injection is internally based on JNDI, I believe.

But it's really a bit of a historical artifact, introduced in the first releases of Java EE, and a part of what gave those a bad reputation, because it was inconvenient to use. Cleaner, simpler forms of DI emerged later with Spring and have since been adopted in Java EE.

Answer (score 0):

When the directory service is known to be LDAP, programmers should avoid using JNDI. Even if the directory is not known or could change, JNDI is a poor choice. Use the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/) instead. See also ["LDAP: Programming Practices"](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s5/sh/605075ef-e73b-40c6-9a4e-5f8b453cf42b/860bc618b3b1af121730469e7f3325ee).